# Using the same thread for other database operations after it has finished processing

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, oracle11g, batch-processing

I am writing an hibernate application which involves batch processing on the records stored.

Assume there are 30000 records stored in database table and i am using 30 threads.  Each thread processes 1000 records in parallel i.e. batch by batch.  Thread1 processes 1 to 1000 Thread2: 1001 to 2001, etc.  Here process means i am performing a select operation on all of them in a batch. I am processing these records to send them to a web-service by parsing them.

The scenario is there is a column named status in the database table where if the record is accepted by the webservice then the status column of the record is made as 1 else 0.

Now the issue arises here when Thread1 finishes processing records with id's 1 to 1000 and Thread 2 is still processing 1001 to 2001.  Assume the records with id's 5 to 30 and 40 to 50 status are 0 i.e. undelivered to the webservice.  Now my scenario demands the thread which has finished processing i.e. Thread1 should start processing the records with id's 5 to 30 and 40 to 50 and try to redeliver the message in the record to the webservice.

I am using `ExecutorService` for coding the same, how to achieve the above.

Comment: is select really so heavy you need to use 30 thread also for selecting? What about using 1 thread selector and 30 worker threads?

Comment: How many cores do you have available to you?  If it's less than 30 you aren't getting any parallelization out of the excess, just context switching and thrashing. Sounds like an overly complex design to me.

Comment: No i already thought of it processing 30000 records or even more who knows by a single thread is not advisable right, as it takes a lot of time to process and i forgot to mention in the post the batch processing of records and delivery to the webservice needs to happen within a limited time frame of **15 mins**.My machine has 8 cores

Comment: If you could reverse the process - parse, then persist - you wouldn't have this issue.  I'd try to make the parsing an in-memory operation rather than calling out to a web service.

Comment: Parsing happens in memory but the parsed message is sent to webservice and based on its status i make the record's status as 1 or 0.Hope this suffices

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the records 1 to 1000 versus the records 5 to 30.  Are you talking about retrying some operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a shared blocking queue, which is filled with the records you need to process (which means that you select those 30000 records somewhere outside of your `ExecutorService` threads).

Then, in your `Thread` code each thread gets top 1000 ([using this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#drainTo-java.util.Collection-int-)) records from the queue and does it's processing. Here is the important part: the records rejected by a web-service are put back to the queue - so when another executor thread is available it will pick the undelivered.

You would need to add delivery counter to your records and check if a message is redelivered limited number of times (so they aren't redelivered forever if they are somehow malformed).